# CGRectMake returning nil?

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

Is it possible for CGRectMake returning nil for some weird reason? Because I'm getting this crash on some devices:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
(null): unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145de2f0
```

and this is the line of code causing the crash:

```
mirror_crop_filter = GPUImageCropFilter(cropRegion: CGRectMake(0.25, 0, 0.5, 1))
```

---

More details on the crash:

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x256f6c1f __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x32ecec8b objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation                 0x256fc039 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x256f9f57 ___forwarding___ + 714
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2562bdf8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5  Coowl                          0x000f6eec Coowl.MirrorView.init (Coowl.MirrorView.Type)(frame : C.CGRect) -> Coowl.MirrorView (MirrorView.swift:31)
6  Coowl                          0x000f6c9c Coowl.MirrorView.__allocating_init (Coowl.MirrorView.Type)(frame : C.CGRect) -> Coowl.MirrorView (MirrorView.swift)
7  Coowl                          0x000af500 Coowl.EdicaoViewController.init_camera (Coowl.EdicaoViewController)() -> () (EdicaoViewController.swift:213)
8  Coowl                          0x000bf99c Coowl.EdicaoViewController.(viewDidLoad (Coowl.EdicaoViewController) -> () -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1) (EdicaoViewController.swift:114)
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x334388cd _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 372
```

---

Also, if it helps, according to Crashlytics, 95% of the devices getting this error are using Jailbrake.

Comment: CGRectMake never return nil.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason that you believe CGRectMake API return nil value? CGRectMake never return nil because it is inline function that simply setting CGRect and return.
To me, it looks like inside of GPIImageCropFilter has some function that doesn't allow nil (e.g. one of shader functions).

Comment: Well, the only thing I pass to GPUImageCropFilter is the rect created by CGRectMake.. That's why I was asking..

Comment: @PauloCesar, I understand that and that's not the cause of this exception.  the exception caused by inside of GPUImageCropFilter initialisation code and I am guessing it is about shader function or GL function's version differences...